# Set Display Name Via Jenkins Build With Parameters

Tags: jenkins-api

I would like to set the build's display name from the Jenkins `buildWithParameters` API?  Specifically, when I POST to `http://my.jenkins.server/job/IntegrationTests/build?delay=0sec`, what parameter can I pass to Jenkins to cause it to change the build's display name?  The default names such as `#42` make it hard to find a particular build.  I tried the following parameters:

- build.displayName
- buildName
- id
- name
- displayName
- description

None of these worked.